# Can props and states be modified by the user directly?

Tags: react-native

I just recently started learning react native, and I was wondering about the following:
If I add special features on components, activated from `this.props.nav.premium_flag` for example, can a user manually set this value and unlock special features without permissions ?

If this was a web application, it would be as easy as opening the browser debugger console and executing `this.props.nav.navigationContext.emit(':flags', { premium_flag: true };`

Are there similar ways to inject javascript into react native applications from android or iphone devices ?